# I am trying to make some movement of sprite node object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make some movement of sprite node object.
But i don't know how to do that because i am new to Sprite Kit.

1. Firstly, object bottom will be fixed.
2. Movement only from top of that object
3. And that object will fall down from top to back.

Comment: add some sample codes to show that you have a real question.

Answer (score 0):

You can move SpriteKit nodes in at least 4 different ways:

- manually setting position on scene update
- applying animations
- applying forces/impulses
- using GameplayKit agents